# I want a query for multiple windowed results (SQL Server 2012+)

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

```
Date (A)    B           C        D      E           F          G        H       I           
27-Feb-15   -100000.00  2,000           2,000       50         -2000    2000    -100,000.00             
02-Mar-15   -80000.00   1,000           3,000       40         -2000    4000    -80,000.00          
29-May-15   30000.00            -600    2,400       30           800    3200     24,000.00          
09-Jul-15   500000.00           -1,200  1,200       20          1600    1600     32,000.00          
26-Oct-15   -2000       800             2,000       40          -50     1650    -2,000.00           
20-Nov-15   1500000             -2,000  0           30          1650    0       49,500.00
```

The table above indicates some financial data that needs to be calculated.  Columns **E**, **G-I** are fields that need to be calculated with a single query without cursors. If this were an excel, the formula for the row 3 would be as following:

```
E: =SUM(C3:D3)+E2

G: =IF(B3<0, B3/F3, -H2*(D3/E2))

H: =H2-G3

I: =F3*G3
```

*Note*: If you are doing this in excel, you need to leave a blank row as row 1 to avoid reference errors.

I think the trickiness for me lies in the fact that you may need multiple windowed functions (using `lag` or `sum` over `partition`), which I'm not sure how to use with SQL-Server, as both columns E and G depend on previous columns results.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
The correct insert statement:

```
insert into t values
 ('27-Feb-15',-100000.00,2000,null,null,50,null,null,null)
 ,('02-Mar-15',-80000.00,1000,null,null,40,null,null,null)
,('29-May-15',30000.00,null,-600,null,30,null,null,null)
,('09-Jul-15',500000.00,null,-1200,null,20,null,null,null)
,('26-Oct-15',-2000,800,null,null,40,null,null,null)
,('20-Nov-15',1500000,null,-2000,null,30,null,null,null);
```

Comment: Im confused, that is your source data or your desire result?. Please you need to include both. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I suggest trying one thing at a time.

Comment: The data sources are columns B, C, D and F.  Those are static data sources.  The rest of the columns are calculated.  It is fairly easy and trivial to do one thing at a time but when you try and combine the logic is when it is beyond my capability with SQL

Answer (score 2):

Using [**`lag()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx):

```
select 
    [Date] 
  , B
  , C
  , D
  , E = (isnull(c,0)+isnull(d,0)) 
        + isnull(lag(e) over (order by [date]),0)
  , F
  , G = convert(decimal(9,2),case 
        when b < 0 
          then b/f
        else (lag(h) over (order by [date])*-1)
            *(d/lag(e) over (order by [date]))
        end)
  , H = lag(h) over (order by [date]) - G
  , I = convert(decimal(9,2),f*g)
from t
order by [date]
```

test setup: http://rextester.com/GRSY3137

returns:

```
+------------+------------+---------+----------+---------+-------+----------+---------+------------+
|    Date    |     B      |    C    |    D     |    E    |   F   |    G     |    H    |     I      |
+------------+------------+---------+----------+---------+-------+----------+---------+------------+
| 2015-02-27 | -100000.00 | 2000.00 | NULL     | 2000.00 | 50.00 | -2000.00 | NULL    | -100000.00 |
| 2015-03-02 | -80000.00  | 1000.00 | NULL     | 3000.00 | 40.00 | -2000.00 | 4000.00 | -80000.00  |
| 2015-05-29 | 30000.00   | NULL    | -600.00  | 2400.00 | 30.00 | 800.00   | 3200.00 | 24000.00   |
| 2015-07-09 | 500000.00  | NULL    | -1200.00 | 1200.00 | 20.00 | 1600.00  | 1600.00 | 32000.00   |
| 2015-10-26 | -2000.00   | 800.00  | NULL     | 2000.00 | 40.00 | -50.00   | 1650.00 | -2000.00   |
| 2015-11-20 | 1500000.00 | NULL    | -2000.00 | 0.00    | 30.00 | 1650.00  | 0.00    | 49500.00   |
+------------+------------+---------+----------+---------+-------+----------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: Unfortunately columns E, G, H, and I are all supposed to be calculated so your code example insert statement should look like the modified insert statement in the edited question above